# SQLBulkCopy using temp table as destination - "Cannot access destination Table" thrown randomly

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an application that uses .NET Framework 4.8, connected to a SQL Server 2019 database. 95% of the time, my bulk copy works just fine.

However, occasionally, I get an error

> Cannot access destination table #MyTempTable

I don't see any network failures, and I don't see anything unusual going on with `tempdb`, however it's a customer environment, so I have limited access to those. The exception in the try/catch block isn't yielding any clues. Any ideas?

Following is basically what the code looks like:

```
using(var bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
{
    var command = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable (MyColumn1 INT, MyColumn2 INT)", conn);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            
    bulkInsert.BatchSize = 5000;
    bulkInsert.BulkCopyTimeout = conn.ConnectionTimeout;
    bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "#MyTempTable";

    DataTable table = CreateDataTableForBulkBatchDetailInsert(bulkInsert);

    PopulateDataTable(table);

    table.AcceptChanges();
    bulkInsert.WriteToServer(table);
}
```

Comment: Use the same connection object (not just connection string) for the SqlCommand and SqlBulkCopy. The connect must remain open to avoid dropping the temp table.

Comment: I can confirm that the same connection is being used.

Comment: Perhaps the amount of time between the `CREATE` and `WriteToServer` is too long and the connection gets reset. Try putting the `CREATE` at the end after `table.AcceptChanges();`. Also you **cannot** have any parameters in that command, because then it will go via `sp_executesql` which is a different scope

Comment: That is definitely a possibility.  I will give that a try.

Comment: Try using a global temp table (## instead of #). It's a quick way to see if your table is occasionally going out of scope due to something not obvious from what you posted.

Comment: A follow up... I have tried all the above, and none is working.  Still digging and will report back.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this @DoodleMum64?